# Spring boot hibernate: cannot delete child object separately

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple setup with two objects, `Event` and `Task` which are linked as parent-child and a default JPA repository for some CRUD operations. I made a test where I attach 2 `Task`s to an `Event`, and then I try to call a `delete` action on one of these `Task`s, which fails (no errors, no deletion either).

If I run the same test without adding the `Task` to the `Event`, the operation succeeds. All my code below, any ideas on what I need to do next?

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "hibernate-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(unique = true)
    String id;

    String subject;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="event", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"event"})
    List<Task> tasks;
}

@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "hibernate-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(unique = true)
    String id;

    String subject;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"tasks"})
    Event event;
}

public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, String> {
    public Task findById(String id);
}
```

And the test:

```
@Test
public void testSequenceOfActionsOnEventWithSubtasks() {
    // Save a new task
    Task savedTask = given()
            .body(
                    new TaskBuilder()
                            .subject("Previously saved task")
                            .build()
            ).contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .when().post(TASKS_RESOURCE).as(Task.class);


    Task unsavedTask = new TaskBuilder()
            .subject("Unsaved task")
            .build();


    // Save a new event with an unsaved and a saved task attached
    Event savedEvent = given()
            .body(
                    new EventBuilder()
                            .subject("Main event")
                            .addTask(savedTask)
                            .addTask(unsavedTask)
                            .build()
            ).contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .when().post(EVENTS_RESOURCE).as(Event.class);


    // Make sure the event now contains two tasks with GUID's attached
    List<Task> tasksForEvent = when().get(EVENT_RESOURCE, savedEvent.getId()).as(Event.class).getTasks();
    assertEquals(2, tasksForEvent.size());

    // Get all tasks, make sure firstTask is in there
    when().get(TASKS_RESOURCE).then().body(SUBJECT_FIELD, hasItems(savedTask.getSubject()));

    // Delete a task that was attached to the event
    when().delete(TASK_RESOURCE, savedTask.getId()).then().statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);

    // Get all tasks, make sure firstTask is NOT in there
    when().get(TASKS_RESOURCE).then().body(SUBJECT_FIELD, not(hasItems(savedTask.getSubject())));

    // Check the event again
    tasksForEvent = when().get(EVENT_RESOURCE, savedEvent.getId()).as(Event.class).getTasks();
    assertEquals(1, tasksForEvent.size());
}
```

UPDATE: if I remove `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` from the `@OneToMany` on in the `Event` class, it works. Would still be nice to know why though. Below is my new `Event` class.

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "hibernate-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(unique = true)
    String id;

    String subject;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="event", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"event"})
    List<Task> tasks;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relevant excerpts from the [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html):

Section **3.2.4**:

> The semantics of the flush operation, applied to an entity X are as
>   follows:
>
> - If X is a managed entity, it is synchronized to the database.
>
>   - For all entities Y referenced by a relationship from X, if the relationship to Y has been annotated with the cascade element value
>       cascade=PERSIST or cascade=ALL, the persist operation is applied to Y

Section **3.2.2**:

> The semantics of the persist operation, applied to an entity X are as
>   follows:
>
> - If X is a removed entity, it becomes managed.

So, what's going on in your case:

1. You delete a `Task`.
2. At the end of the transactions Hibernate synchronizes the persistence context with the database.
3. It finds the `Event` instance. No changes in it, but the `PERSIST` operation is cascaded to the `tasks`.
4. `PERSIST` is applied to all the `Task`s in the `tasks` collection, including the removed one, which becomes managed again.

To verify this, enable the `TRACE` log level for `org.hibernate` package and search for messages containing `un-scheduling entity deletion`.

If the `tasks` are loaded lazily, then `PERSIST` is not applied to them (if the collection is not initialized in the meantime, of course); that's why you don't see this behavior in that case.

The solution is to remove the deleted task from the `Event`'s `tasks` collection also, so that `PERSIST` is not applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

add orphanRemoval=true attribute

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="event", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"event"})
List<Task> tasks;
```